# Certain git commands (diff, log) require sudo priviledges

Tags: permissions, sudo, git

On my Ubuntu 17.10 installation, certain git commands require sudo permissions to run properly (without sudo, they immediately return and print no output), while others do not. The issue is the same for every git repository on my computer, so it seems unrelated to permission in any particular repo. These git commands **require** sudo:

- diff
- log
- show

Those do **not** require sudo:

- add
- commit
- status
- stash
- branch
- checkout

I'm completely stumped, particular by the pattern of allowed/disallowed commands. Any solutions/suggestions for further debugging?

**EDIT:** Issue persists in a new repository. Permissions for the folder (from `ls -la`):

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  3 morten morten 4096 juni   5 20:52 .
drwxrwxr-x 33 morten morten 4096 juni   5 20:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 morten morten 4096 juni   5 20:53 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 morten morten    0 juni   5 20:52 test.txt
```

Comment: This depend on file permissions in your git repo.

Comment: How did you figure out that they require sudo? I ask cause running `sudo git` should never be required.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your user account or to the permissions of the git directories/repos recently?

Comment: Create a new git repo and try.

Comment: I guess trying sudo is just a reflex when things don't work in the terminal. The issue *probably* appeared when I installed 17.10, certainly not before. My home folder is from 16.04. Question has been updated with file permissions for test repo.

Comment: What do you mean by "require"? What happens when you don't use sudo?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. They complete instantly without printing anything.

Comment: Please add the output of `strace git log` (or `strace` any of the other git commands that don't work)

Answer (score 0):

Could some of the objects in your .git got their file ownership messed up? You can try changing the ownership and try the git commands again without sudo.

```
sudo chown -R morten:morten .git
```

Also check your .git/config and ~/.gitconfig to make sure you don't have something setup for diff, log and show that requres sudo.

Comment: Your command didn't help, unfortunately. .git/config is just the default 5 lines in my empty test repo. ~/.gitconfig also only has the bare necessities.

Comment: May be some files are held open, can you try the following to check: lsof +D .git

Comment: That did not return anything except a warning about not being able to stat() a fuse file system.

Comment: That command list all open file handles for .git directory and shouldn't return an error. If you do get an error, and not getting one when doing sudo lsof +D .git, you are closer to knowing why non-sudo failed for some git command you tried.